# get the digest of a docker tar archive

Tags: docker

How do I get the digest of a docker tar archive?  Using the code below, I pull **hello-world**, get the digest of the image, and finally, save it as hello-world.tar.

```
docker pull hello-world
docker save hello-world > hello-world.tar

# Get the digest of the image **loaded into docker**
docker images --digests --filter=reference='hello-world'

REPOSITORY    TAG       DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
hello-world   latest    sha256:faa03e786c97f07ef34423fccceeec2398ec8a5759259f94d99078f264e9d7af   feb5d9fea6a5   14 months ago   13.3kB
```

How can I get the digest from **hello-world.tar**? I'm expecting it to match the digest `sha256:faa03e7...` in the output shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you untar `hello-world.tar`, you'll see:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep 23  2021 c28b9c2faac407005d4d657e49f372fb3579a47dd4e4d87d13e29edd1c912d5c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  1469 Sep 23  2021 feb5d9fea6a5e9606aa995e879d862b825965ba48de054caab5ef356dc6b3412.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 24064 Dec  8 17:48 hello-world.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   207 Jan  1  1970 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    94 Jan  1  1970 repositories
```

The manifest.json file has a field that shows you the name of the config file:

```
cat manifest.json | jq '.[0].Config'

"feb5d9fea6a5e9606aa995e879d862b825965ba48de054caab5ef356dc6b3412.json"
```

If you inspect the Docker image loaded on the system for hello-world, you'll see that the name of the config file is the same as the SHA256 digest in the `Id` field:

```
docker inspect hello-world | jq '.[0].Id'

"sha256:feb5d9fea6a5e9606aa995e879d862b825965ba48de054caab5ef356dc6b3412"
```

This way, you can compare the 2 digest values, one from the loaded Docker image and one from the static tar.gz file.